# CakePHP 3 query combining IF/AND/OR

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

How can I implement this code in CakePHP 3?

```
function notEmpty($field) {
    return isset($field) && $field != '';
}

$conditions[] = notEmpty($group_id) ? "group_id LIKE %$group_id%" : '';
$conditions[] = notEmpty($token) ? "firstname LIKE %$token% OR lastname LIKE %$token% OR username LIKE %$token%" : '';
$conditions[] = notEmpty($parent_id) ? "parent_id LIKE %$parent_id%" : '';
$conditions[] = notEmpty($status) ? "status1 LIKE %$status% AND status2 LIKE %$status%" : '';

$conditions = array_filter($conditions , function($value) { return $value !== ''; });//Remove empty conditions
array_walk($conditions, function(&$item) { $item = "($item)"; });//Add () to conditions
$where = !empty($conditions) ? 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $conditions) : '';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users '.$where;
```

I'm using pagination.

Comment: It's been a long time I came accross so many possible SQL injection vulnerabilities in so little code (no offense)! **_NEVER EVER_** add (user)data into queries directly, **ALWAYS** use prepared queries when building custom SQL! That being said, what have you tried? Do you know anything about the CakePHP 3 ORM at all? If not, I'd highly recommend that you study the docs first: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html** | **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html**

Comment: That's why I want to implement this code via cake not php :) I can do this for simple codes, But I don't know how can I do above. Because it's a complicated code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple code :) Definately not complicated.

Simplest and most direct  answer is the code below (Assuming the Users table):

```
$conditions = [];
if (!empty($group_id)) {
  $conditions['group_id LIKE'] = '%' . $group_id . '%';
}
if (!empty($token)) {
  $conditions['or'] = [
    'firstname LIKE' => '%' . $token . '%',
    'lastname LIKE' => '%' . $token . '%',
    'username LIKE' => '%' . $token . '%',
  ];
}
if (!empty($parent_id)) {
  $conditions['parent_id LIKE'] = '%' . $parent_id . '%';
}
if (!empty($status)) {
  $conditions['status1 LIKE'] = '%' . $status . '%';
  $conditions['status2 LIKE'] = '%' . $status . '%';
}
$query = $this->Users->find()->where($conditions);
```

You can then easily pass `$query` to the `paginate()` method in the controller.

A better, more robust and maintainable solution is to the use FriendsOfCake Search plugin https://github.com/friendsofcake/search